# replaceAll function in javscript doesn't replace all occurrences

Tags: javascript, regex, replaceall

I have the following snippet:

```js
const paragraph = '1\t1\t150\t18\t\"Pack of 12 action figures (variety)\"\t18\t9\t5.50\t2013-01-02 00:00:00.0000000\tTrue\t6\t2013-01-02 07:00:00.0000000\r\n2\t1\t151\t21\t\"Pack of 12 action figures (male)\"\t21\t9\t5.50\t2013-01-02 00:00:00.0000000\tTrue\t6\t2013-01-02 07:00:00.0000000\r\n3\t1\t152\t18\t\"Pack of 12 action figures (female)\"\t18\t9\t5.50\t2013-01-02 00:00:00.0000000\tTrue\t6\t2013-01-02 07:00:00.0000000\r\n4\t2\t76\t8\t\"\\\"The ';
const regex = /(?!\B"[^"]*)\t(?![^"]*"\B)/g;
const found = paragraph.replaceAll(regex, ',');

console.log(found);
```

This snippet should match all of `\t`, except the ones between quotes, from `paragraph` and replace them all with comma `,`. However, all of them don't get replaced as the text I parse looks like this:

```
'1,1,150,18,"Pack of 12 action figures (variety)",18,9,5.50,2013-01-02 00:00:00.0000000,True,6,2013-01-02 07:00:00.0000000
2,1,151,21,"Pack of 12 action figures (male)",21,9,5.50,2013-01-02 00:00:00.0000000,True,6,2013-01-02 07:00:00.0000000
3,1,152,18,"Pack of 12 action figures (female)" 18  9   5.50    2013-01-02 00:00:00.0000000 True    6   2013-01-02 07:00:00.0000000
4   2   76  8   "\"The '
```

After `(female)"`, the `\t` doesn't get replaced at all but it should as it replaces `\t` in first and second row. What am I doing wrong, any ideas?

Comment: FWIW, it's not `replaceAll` that's the problem. That regex doesn't match the tab you've mentioned: https://regex101.com/r/idbILn/1 (If I knew why not, I'd post an answer, but... :-) )

Comment: Hm, thanks! Didn't think of that because it works for almost every case but except this one :)

Comment: I'm also fairly sure the negative lookahead at the beginning of the string isn't useful, because if there's a `\t` there, by definition it isn't `\B"[^"]*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```js
const paragraph = '1\t1\t150\t18\t\"Pack of 12 action figures (variety)\"\t18\t9\t5.50\t2013-01-02 00:00:00.0000000\tTrue\t6\t2013-01-02 07:00:00.0000000\r\n2\t1\t151\t21\t\"Pack of 12 action figures (male)\"\t21\t9\t5.50\t2013-01-02 00:00:00.0000000\tTrue\t6\t2013-01-02 07:00:00.0000000\r\n3\t1\t152\t18\t\"Pack of 12 action figures (female)\"\t18\t9\t5.50\t2013-01-02 00:00:00.0000000\tTrue\t6\t2013-01-02 07:00:00.0000000\r\n4\t2\t76\t8\t\"\\\"The ';
const regex = /("[^"]*")|\t/g;
const found = paragraph.replace(regex, (whole_match,group_one) => group_one || ',' );

console.log(found);
```

The `/("[^"]*")|\t/g` regex matches all occurrences of strings between double quotation marks capturing them into Group 1 or TAB char in other contexts.

If Group 1 matches, the replacement is Group 1 value, else, the replacement is a comma.